# Bamboo shows testcases are 0 even though there are testcases in the application

Tags: c#, sonarqube, mstest, bamboo

In Bamboo portal, I have created different tasks in which I checkout the code and fetch latest code, build the solution using MSBuild, run the Sonarqube analysis using Scripts.

The scripts also contains the scripts for running the testcases.This is how it looks.

Task1 : Source code checkout configuration : I have selected the repository name.

Task2 : Command Configuration : This steps restores the Nuget packages into the solution

Task3 : Script Configuration : Start Sonar Scanner
Script used is :

```
"C:\sonar-scanner-msbuild-net461\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" begin /k:"ProjectKey" /n:"ProjectName" /v:"1" /d:sonar.host.url="SonarqubeURL" /d:sonar.login=435454352345fgdfdsfvdc342434 /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="C:\Project\Application.coveragexml"
```

Task4 : Command Configuration : MSBuild : Builds the solution

Task5 : Script Configuration : Run unit Tests:
Scripts used :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" collect /output:"C:\Project\Application.coverage" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "TestProject\bin\Release\TestProject.dll"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" analyze /output:"C:\Project\Application.coveragexml" "C:\Project\Application.coverage"
```

Task6 : Script Configuration : End Sonar Scanner

```
"C:\sonar-scanner-msbuild-net461\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" end /d:sonar.login=435454352345fgdfdsfvdc342434
```

These are the tasks in my stage in Bamboo. Task6 publishes the results of testcases to SonarqubeURL. Now this is all happening as expected.

But when I run this plan, it shows it is a testless build. Task5 is running all the testcases, but how to make Bamboo know that the test cases are running. Also , if any of the unit testcases are failing, how to show it like test cases passed :X , failed :Y.

Is there any additional step am I missing? Any help is much appreciated.

PS : This is a windows service in c# and used MStest for writing testcases.

Comment: Oops, I answered a question you did not ask :) I'll delete my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Most testing tools (including VSTest I think) emit test result XML files that are compatible with the JUnit format.  You need to add a parse JUnit Files step after  you run your tests and configure it to parse the files that are created.  Note you can run the build locally to figure out where those files are created.

Here is the documentation on the JUnit Parser task:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/junit-parser-289277056.html

(Atlassian provides excellent documentation of its products BTW)

Comment: yes, XML files are created while running the above (question) mentioned scripts.I also know the path where are getting generated. Can you please explain a more about "You need to add a parse JUnit Files step after you run your tests and configure it to parse the files that are created".

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to the JUnit Parser task

Comment: My apologies for replying so late. I have added this task and tested. In the documentation it is written that we should not specify absolute path. But my code is in directory : "<bamboo-home>/xml-data/build-dir/JOB_KEY/" and my .coveragexml files are generated in another folder in "C:\Project\Application.coveragexml". How should i specify the path then.

Comment: So - you either need to move the xml file into the working directory or specify the absolute path.  In most CI tools your code is checked out to a directory on the build agent. In Bamboo, that location is referenced by the bamboo.build.working.directory variable and is the default directory for your build tasks. Using absolute directories like C:\Project is not a good idea because it isn't job specific so it doesn't scale. Also you may run into file/directory protection issues.  That's why all file references should be relative to the working directory.